# System.ArgumentException was unhandled - String cannot be of zero length

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is the method:

```
public void CheckFileType(string directoryPath)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).GetEnumerator();
    while (files.MoveNext())
    {
        //get file extension 
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(files.Current));

        //get file name without extenstion 
        string fileName =
          Convert.ToString(files.Current).Replace(fileExtension, string.Empty);

        //Check for JPG File Format 
        if (fileExtension == ".jpg" || fileExtension == ".JPG")
        // or // ImageFormat.Jpeg.ToString()
        {
            try
            {
                //OCR Operations ... 
                MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();
                md.Create(Convert.ToString(files.Current));
                md.OCR(MODI.MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH, true, true);
                MODI.Image image = (MODI.Image)md.Images[0];

                //create text file with the same Image file name 
                FileStream createFile =
                  new FileStream(fileName + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);
                //save the image text in the text file 
                StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(createFile);
                writeFile.Write(image.Layout.Text);
                writeFile.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //uncomment the below code to see the expected errors
                w.Write(exc.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
    w.Close();
}
```

Its working when the variable files.Current contain a file name: RadarGifAnimatoion and the file type is just: File 
I did properties on the file and under Type i see just: File
This file size is 32 bytes i guess the file is bad or empty.

Then im getting the exception on the line:

```
string fileName = Convert.ToString(files.Current).Replace(fileExtension, string.Empty);
```

> String cannot be of zero length
>
> System.ArgumentException was unhandled   HResult=-2147024809
>   Message=String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue
>   Source=mscorlib   ParamName=oldValue

Comment: Have you looked at the stacktrace?

Comment: `Replace(fileExtension, string.Empty)` will throw this error when `fileExtension` is an empty string - i.e. when the file has no extension ("file type is just FILE")

Comment: You can use this to fix your code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx

Comment: @Blorgbeard That's certainly an option, but [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) seems more straightforward. I like how closely the method name matches the comment in the OP's code.

Comment: @hvd Look what he's doing with the extensionless path though - he is reimplementing ChangeExtension :P

Comment: If you really need to do it this way then look at the `Path` methods - like [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Comment: @DanielVest: You can simplify your code with this: `var jpegsToTxts = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Where(file => Path.GetExtension(file).ToUpper() == ".JPG").Select(file => new {OldFile = file, NewFile = Path.ChangeExtension(file, "txt")}).ToList();` Then you can iterate those and access their `OldFile` property (the "jpg" file path) and `NewFile` property ("txt" path)

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Dangerously too. A file like `myimage.jpgbadname.jpg" would change incorrectly. (albeit, for jpg, it's a pretty contrived case. But still, this are the kinds of things that bugs are made of.)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair yes, noticed that. You should post your comment above as an answer, I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oldValue in `Replace` (first parameter) can not be zero length.
If it is a ArgumentException is thrown

[Microsofts documentation for Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) contains information about exceptions that can be thrown by the function.